# Graphql query in Python

Tags: python, graphql

[Here](https://granddebat.fr/graphiql?query=%7B%20%20node(id%3A%20"UXVlc3Rpb25uYWlyZTo5NTNjYjdjYS0xY2E0LTExZTktOTRkMi1mYTE2M2VlYjExZTE%3D")%20%7B%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Questionnaire%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20replies(first%3A%2010%2C%20after%3A%20null)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasNextPage%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20publishedAt%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20updatedAt%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20author%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20responses%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20question%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20ValueResponse%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%7D%7D) is a graphql query with its result : OK.

I try to get the same result with Python, but I get nothing : response.text is empty. (API key is not needed).

```
q = """
{
  node(id: "UXVlc3Rpb25uYWlyZTo5NTNjYjdjYS0xY2E0LTExZTktOTRkMi1mYTE2M2VlYjExZTE=") {
    ... on Questionnaire {
      replies(first: 10, after: null) {
        totalCount
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          node {
            id
            createdAt
            publishedAt
            updatedAt
            author {
              id
            }
            responses {
              question {
                title
              }
              ... on ValueResponse {
                value
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

response = requests.post(url = "https://granddebat.fr/graphql" , json = {'query': q})

print(response.text)
```

Please, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all good with the query itself. In request you need to pass headers with `{'Accept': 
'application/vnd.cap-collectif.preview+json'}`

```py
response = requests.post(
    url = "https://granddebat.fr/graphql",
    json = {'query': q,},
    headers= {'Accept': 'application/vnd.cap-collectif.preview+json'}
)
```

Comment: Thank you !! It's OK with headers !